# Why doesnt the HTML5 nav tag behave as expected?

Tags: css, html

In the following code the nav tag does not behave as I thought it was supposed to (and align with the bottom of the page.)
In firebug the nav it does not appear, even after the overflow: hidden; style. However if I apply the position: absolute, bottom: 0 to ul it works. 
Why is this happening? nav does not seem useful in this context.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio">porfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact">contact us</a></li>
            </ul>         
        </nav>      
    </header>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```css
header {
    background: url(../img/header-bg.jpg) left top no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    }

/* navigation */
nav {
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #72aa21;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    }
nav ul {
    display:inline-block;
    }
nav li {
    display: inline;
    }
nav ul li a {
    line-height: 2.6em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 .5em;
    padding-left: 1.6em;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<nav>` is actually positioned at the bottom as you told it to. However, it also has 100% height, and its contents are at the top.

Just remove `height: 100%` and you should be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qHvB4/

Comment: it does not work in my browser even without height:100%; As I said in firebug does not appear with inspect element, and I do not understand why/

Comment: the jsfiddle I linked to won't work either? if it's only your own code, on your browser, recheck the code again, your html is probably invalid at some point.

Comment: I figured it out. You were right, it was a problem in my code. The min-height was defined after the position: relative and apparently this makes the position attribute behave differently. It works now, heads up for the ppl with the same problem.